# We wished we didn't go in?

Tags: meaning, phrases, verbs, tenses, past-tense

Put the verbe in the correct tense

"On this occasion we did, but once inside in the establishment we wished we ____ (not go) in.

I would say "we wished we didn't go in"

Comment: That would probably be wrong; I think the test maker was looking for _had not gone in_. The wishing was in the past, and it referred to an earlier past time, and that's the situation that the past perfect construction is designed for. English can handle up to two different past times in the same narrative, but any more and we get confused.

Comment: @JohnLawler - You should propose your comment as an answer.

Comment: The problem is there are multiple possibilities, all grammatical. Without more specific information about *why* something is what's expected, any answer would be pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several possibilities depending on meaning, by far the most likely is that you want the pluperfect.

The wishing is in the past (we wished) and it is referring to something that is in the past relative to the wishing. Under these  circumstances the required tense is the pluperfect:

> We went in to the establishment, and then we wished we **hadn't** gone in.